# Choosing Correct Database for My Needs

Tags: android, mysql, ios, database, sqlite

I am in the preliminary stages of designing a smartphone app (will be available on iOS, Android, Windows Phone). I am just learning all of this. I am trying to find the right database for my needs.

This database will eventually have high-traffic, has to be able to integrate into an app, and maybe even use a website later on. The app will send and receive data from the database. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

I know SQLite works well in apps, but can it support high-traffic apps that have users uploading a lot of data at the same time? To recap, it must be: accessible from an app, support high-traffic, send and receive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccommend MySQL, which I see you have tagged in your question already. I'm using MySQL for a Survey applcation and I havent had any problems with it. I get information from the Server via php.

Basic outline of what my app does:

iPhone App connects to the url for the php script, inputting correct arguments --> php script contacts the database --> php returns values --> iphone app stores the variables for use in obj-c

You can store sqlite database right in your application, but I never needed to do so. Hope this helps.